# Javascript iFrame Limitations

Tags: javascript, iframe

I know that, for security reasons, javascript can't read the contents of an iframe if it belongs to a different domain. This makes sense, given that the entire page could be an iframe with snooping scripts outside of the frame.

The question is - are there equal limitations in the other direction? Can javascript within an iframe (from a different domain) read and manipulate the dom in its parent window?

Thanks!

Comment: The limitations are the same in both directions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.
This would be a security hole. Now that everyone is crazy adding facebook iframes to their sites, imagine if javascript from FB could interact with your page ;)
Anyway, i set up a small example, and got the same origin warning when i tried to get a parent's div from inside the iframe (which was in another domain)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this in a two domains that you own (not trying to attack anyone) you can do that using ajax as described [Here.](http://softwareas.com/cross-domain-communication-with-iframes)